# Adding file size and other info to a find

Tags: linux

I am currently using the following linux command:

```
find /folder -size +1000k | grep txt
```

to find in the "folder" any files with "txt" in it that has a size greater than 1000k bytes.

This succesfully returns the list of files that I want. But I would also like to print out the file size, and if I can, to see last date modified within the returned list of files (much like what the command ll returns)

I tried using `printf %s`, but this simply returns a list of numbers, thus the grep doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, I tend to disagree with the move-to-superuser close reason for this one -- unambiguously reading size data from `find` is an operation that comes up fairly often in scripting, and there are some nonintuitive bits to doing it right (putting the size before the name, NUL-delimiting the records, using multiple `read` commands to read both fields in a way that doesn't trim trailing whitespace or have other undesired effects, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First -- there's absolutely no reason to use `grep` on output from `find`; you can just tell `find` to do the filtering itself.

Second -- the `-printf` action takes a format string which can have more than one specifier. For instance, `%s %P\n`, to print first size, then name, then a newline. (This ordering is desirable since size will always be a single string of digits, whereas a name can be undefined -- so putting the name first makes it harder to parse).

```
find /folder -size +1000k -name '*txt*' -printf '%s %P\n'
```

Mind you -- to be completely unambiguously parsed, you'll want to use NUL specifiers rather than newlines, since newlines are valid inside filenames.

---

An example which reads filenames and sizes into a pair of bash arrays, after sorting by size:

```
files=( )
sizes=( )
while IFS= read -r -d' ' size && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  files+=( "$filename" )
  sizes+=( "$size" )
done < <(find /folder -size +1000k -name '*txt*' -printf '%s %P\0' | sort -n -z)
```

Comment: Thanks, this returned what I needed. Is there any way to sort this by file size, or add some kind of formatting to file size to more easily see the results?

Once again thanks for the help

Comment: Just pipe to `sort -n` to sort by size (another advantage to putting the size first).

Comment: thanks, I'm totally new to linux. Trying to figure this stuff out as I go...If you don't mind, could you explain when to use | in between commands? (I could always look it up so feel free to ignore the question :) )

Comment: @socool111, pipes connect the stdout channel of the command on the left to the stdin of the command on the right. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide for an introduction which will cover this and other topics.